# div tags doesn't remain fixed if page is zoomed in or zoomed out

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a bootstrap template html code:

```
<section id="main-content">
  <section class="wrapper">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Create New Space Marine Chapter</h3>       
      <div class="row mt" >
          <div class="col-md-12" >
              <div class="content-panel" >
              <form class="form-inline" action="add.php" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-5" style='float:initial;width:680px;height:240px'>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="id">ID:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ID" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="name">Name:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="founding">Founding:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Founding" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="successor_of">Successor Of:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Successor_Of" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="successor_chapters">Successor Chapters:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Successor_Chapters" required="required"/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="number">Number:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Number" required="required"/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="primarch">Primarch:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Primarch" required="required"/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="chapter_master">Chapter Master:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Chapter_Master" required="required"/>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="homeworld">Homeworld:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Homeworld" required="required"/>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="allegiance">Allegiance:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Allegiance" required="required"/>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="colors">Colors:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Colors" required="required"/>
                        </div>                                                              
                    </div>                                                        
                </div>  
                <br>                          
                <div class="form-group col-md-1 ">
                    <button onclick="showAddRecordDiv()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
                </div>                            
              </form>                                                                                              
                <form action="javascript:getLastRecord();" method="GET">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Show Last Created</button>
                    </div>
                </form>                                        
                <form action="javascript:getAllRecords();" method="GET">
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Show All</button>
                    </div> 
                                                  
                </form>
                  <table id="advanced-table" class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">                   
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center" width="50">ID</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" width="100">Name</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Founding</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" width="150">Successor Of</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" width="200" >Successor Chapters</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Number</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Primarch</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" width="200" >Chapter Master</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Homeworld</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Allegiance</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Colors</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" width="100" >Input Date</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center" >Delete</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>   
                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>                          
                  </table>
                  <div id="alert-div" class="alert alert-danger" hidden="hidden">
                        <strong>RECORD DELETED</strong>                           
                        </div>  
                  <div id="add-record-div" class="alert alert-success" hidden="hidden">
                        <strong>CHAPTER CREATED</strong>    
                  </div>
              </div><!-- /content-panel -->
          </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
      </div><!-- /row -->
</section><! --/wrapper -->
</section><!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
```

My problem is when I zoom in or out the page, all divs' positions changes and page's layout brakes. Here is some examples:
Page with size of 33%:
[image: Page with size of 33%]

Page with size of 100%:
[image: Page with size of 100%]

Page with size of 175%:
[image: Page with size of 175%]

I searched over internet and saw that I must set divs' sizes fixed/static. I did something with float and width-height but it didn't help. What can I do for not to break page's layout?

Comment: @j08691 I'm completely using bootstrap css. This was a bootstrap page, I only changed colors, some style and added few javascript and buttons.

Comment: Can you show us yor css code? ... from what you tell, I believe setting `display: block;` to your `<label ...>` tags should fix the problem

Comment: @leo.fcx I think I can't because it's bootstrap css and its huge. I'm using 'dashgum' bootstrap template. Here is the link so if it helps, you can look at it from here: http://www.blacktie.co/2014/07/dashgum-free-dashboard/#more-362

Comment: Understood, but did you try what I said (custon css style)? .. something like this: `.form-group label {display: block;}`

Comment: @leo.fcx Divs and buttons layout still change in below 50% and above 200% but between 50%-200% layout is same. It partially solved the problem thank you anyway!

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess ... if you could provide a fiddle I could take a look